# Deducing non-similarilty of two matrices from a glance

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two matrices: $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

What is the best way to see that these two matrices are not similar (preferably, just by looking at it maybe, rather than showing that there does not exist an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}BP$)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar matrices have the same rank.